Incorrect Animation when exporting as Collada file
I have 2 files. A .fbx file containing animated bones and an .obj file containing a 3d model of an axe. I want the 3d model to be animated by the bones from the .fbx file.
When I import both into a new blender file and then play the animation, only the bones move. So far so good.
I select the 3d model, hold Shift and click on the bones. Then Ctrl+P and I select "Armature Deform With Automatic Weights".

This makes it so the 3d model is now also animated, but only part of it. The stick correctly moves but the head of the axe moves incorrectly.
Frame 1: (Head of Axe is still in correct position)

Frame 12: (Head of Axe moves around but in a wrong position)

My game engine requires the animation to be in Collada file format. ALthough the animation looking wrongly I can still export it as a Collada file and import it into my game without problem.
To get the head of the 3d model be animated correctly I tried to set it's parent to "Bone".

Now the animation works correctly as can be seen here:

However since I'm missing weights now, I can only export a Collada file without weights which my game can't import then.
If I manually weight-paint the axe, the import into my game works but the animation is incorrect again, that is, the axe just flies around in a completely unintended way - certainly not what the animated bones define.
What am I missing here?
PS: Before exporting I have already applied all transforms both for the bones and the axe mesh.

I posted an answer. If it doesn't solve the issue, please [edit] your question and show the result in the game engine (which one?), it would also be a good idea to share your file.

Automatic weights will try to assign each vertex to nearby bones. The issue here is that you want the whole model to be assigned to one bone, but you ask Blender to assign it to multiple.
There is possibly another issue of your objects having unapplied transforms or offsets it shouldn't have when parented.
So first, let's do a cleanup to make sure you are working on a sane base.
Cleanup

In object mode, select the armature and press ⎇ AltG and ⎇ AltS to clear its location and scale. I don't think you need to clear the rotation since the importer might have added 90⁰ somewhere to compensate a different source orientation, but it shouldn't be an issue.

Then move your axe model where it should be relative to the bone it should follow.

Finally, select the two objects, hit AlpP >, Clear Parent And Keep Transformations.


Hit ⎈ CtrlA > Apply Rotation & Scale. You might need to then select only the axe object and hit ⎈ CtrlA > Apply Location. As for the armature object, it should be at the center of the scene anyway.

Go to your object's modifiers tab and delete all Armature Deform modifiers.

In the mesh data tab > Vertex Groups panel, if you see any group, click the   ̌   button and hit Delete All Groups.


Parenting
Instead of parenting to Armature Deform with Automatic Weights, assign it to Armature Deform, with Empty Groups. This will create the vertex groups for each bone, but without assigning them to any vertex.
↹ Tab into Edit Mode, select all vertices, select the vertex group named after the bone to which you want to parent the model to, and hit the Assign button.

Then ↹ Tab into object mode, and the axe should be following the armature correctly.

Thank you, I followed your description and it worked! I even had to apply all transforms during the cleanup to make it work correctly. I'm so happy now. :-)
